# How To Get table columns with some condition in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

**Here is the situation like:**

I am Having the table structure like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  FieldName                  data_type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
surveyForm_1_id       varchar(255)
survey_form_id        varchar(255)
submitted_by          varchar(255)
submitted_on          varchar(255)   
field_name_1          varchar(255)
field_name_2          varchar(255)   
field_name_3          varchar(255)   
field_name_4          varchar(255)
field_name_5          varchar(255)   
field_name_6          varchar(255)   
field_name_7              varchar(255)
```

With Mysql Query i wanted to remove the following fiels from mytable..........

```
surveyForm_1_id 
survey_form_id  
submitted_by    
submitted_on
```

For that I have Tried The Query as:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM surveyform_1
```

Anyone just suggest me...

I want the Query Which will give result fieldset as like

```
field_name_1     
field_name_2         
field_name_3         
field_name_4     
field_name_5         
field_name_6         
field_name_7
```

Comment: It's impossible to understand your question, which is not even a question by the way. what have you tried, what is the result, what is the expected result ?

Comment: So you want to list all of the columns like `field_name_*`?

Comment: Siva - a better option for you may be the [MySQL Tutorial on Retrieving Information from a Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/retrieving-data.html). Please give that a read; it will probably answer your question.

Comment: hey Guys.... First one i have mentioned the structure of my table....

Comment: Siva, clarify your question

Comment: Why you want that particular column list and not all columns, I'm asking because there might be another  approach for ur problem.

Comment: what i have mentioned that columns wont come dynamically.....

Comment: (@javad: in general, if someone has already asked for a clarification, it's not helpful for several people to do so as well! Also, do try to be polite, even if someone is relatively new here `:)`).

Comment: @Siva, are you looking for the **values** of those columns, rather than their names?

Comment: no only columns..........i got the answer........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM surveyform_1 WHERE Field LIKE 'field_name_%'
```

Comment: exactly i want this bro............ thanks a lot............

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM surveyform_1 WHERE SUBSTRING(Field,1,11) = "field_name_";
```

Comment: it is not a correct one sry......

Comment: well, I don't mind you choose the other way, but you can't say this is not correct :) it will work too.

Comment: no bro i am getting empty result with your query...........

Comment: Ok I misspelled the start index as mysql substring indexes starts with "1". Not "0".

Comment: nw it is fine working............